# React Native: How to check login status?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I am using react native router flex for navigation and I have 2 scene A and B,also using redux for storing state.
if user login status is true the app will redirect to Page B else Page A.
But I am unable to check the status.componentDidMount always getting false state.

Page A:

```
componentDidMount () {
if(status)
    {

      Actions.b();
    }

}


const mapStateToProps = ({userData}) => {

const {
status,
  } = userData;
  return {
    status,
  };

}
```

Let me know how to check login status.

Comment: perhaps the status is changed much later, try logging status in your render method to see if it turns to true.

Comment: if i add inside render method page B is reloading again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `componentWillReceiveProps`. As soon as your status changes, your component will route to the next screen.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.status) {
    Actions.b();
  }
}
```